# Connection refused when trying to connect by ssh

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, ssh

I am unable to remotely connect to the raspberry pi armhf that I have now flashed with ubuntu 20.04. I followed the steps for installing the ssh server. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-ssh-on-ubuntu-20-04/

1. Open the terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T and install the openssh-server package:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install openssh-server
   ```
2. Once the installation is complete, the SSH service will start automatically. You can verify that SSH is running by typing:

   ```
   sudo systemctl status ssh
   ```
3. Ubuntu ships with a firewall configuration tool called UFW. If the firewall is enabled on your system, make sure to open the SSH port:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow ssh
   ```

[image]

After completing this I am able to local connect with `ssh localhost` but I can not when I try from my windows 10 laptop. I get the following error message:

```
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:00000267052E5570
debug1: connect to adress 127.0.0.1 port 22: connection refused
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

The IP address that you're trying to `ssh` into is incorrect. `127.0.0.1` is 'localhost': it's a special IP address that a computer can use to refer to itself. As a result, that's totally valid to ssh into the Pi from the Pi, but when you try it on your laptop, you're asking your laptop to SSH into itself.

Instead, you need to specify the IP address of your raspberry pi. You can find the IP address using the `ip` command: type `ip addr` and you should get a list of entries. Each entry will have some 'inet' value, and that's the IP address of that device. First you'll see a `lo` entry, which is the local device, then you'll see other IP addresses that will allow your Pi to be accessed from other computers.

Comment: Thanks that clarified a bunch. It never connected to the wifi network. Makes sense now. I will connect to an ethernet cable first and then will try setting up the wireless connection.